# Firebase auth propagation time for Firestore rules?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

Am calling these functions in sequence (javascript 'firebase`):

```
firebase
  .auth()
  .signInWithEmailLink(email, url)
  .then(userCred => {
     return firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc('someDocID').get()
     ....
```

I have security rules setup in firestore that allows read of 'users/:docId' only if the email field in that document equals the auth email:
`allow get: if request.auth.token.email == resource.data.email`

The problem is we get a missing or insufficient permissions error on the `get()`.
For sure the email in the database is correct so the only problem could be is that `request.auth.token.email` is not valid.
Could it be that signing in (using any sign in function), even if resolves, doesn't guarantee the auth token is updated and can be immediately used ?

Is there propagation time? should we call `getIdToken()` after sign in resolves to make sure the token is valid before making database/firestore calls?

Comment: Calling `signInWithEmailLink` will get an ID token with the latest values, which is then cached for about an hour. Are you saying that you actively sign in by calling `signInWithEmailLink` and see outdated properties? Can you log those in your code and show the updated code and its output?

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen, I can only see that randomly (not always) the FS `get()` called right after sign in resolves fails with a permissions problem. My understanding of your comment  - after sign in resolves there should be no issue with the token sent to FS rules so its safe to use it that way - and thats what I'm trying to verify.

Comment: To verify you'll want to log the values from the user profile right before you make the problematic Firestore call.

Comment: Problem is this happens in customer use - not in our testing and we are not able to reproduce it in controlled env.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a user actively signs in (by calling any of the `signInWith...` methods), the client gets an ID token, which contains the up-to-date values for that user. That ID token is valid for an hour, and is then auto-refreshed by the client/SDK.

So right after the `signIn...` call, the profile should contain the latest values. If you think something is going wrong there, I'd recommend logging the values right before making the call to Firestore.

Comment: just to complete the picture. Turns out the problem was indeed with the security rules - emails in auth tokens are always lowercased while the DB entries might be lower or uppercases so the rule failed ‍♂️